# Angular JS error var undefined

Tags: angularjs

Boa noite 
tenho essa função https://pastebin.com/mZB1KtnS
se dou um alert(data); dentro da funçao (abaixo do data) ok, mas se invoco a função no controller da undefined.
Como posso resolver? 
obrigado

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.convertMd5 = function (string) { // retorna string em md5
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '../assets/php/client/Users.php',
        data: {ref: 'convert-md5', str: string},
        dataType: 'html',
    });
}
$scope.convertMs5('aaaa').success(function (data) {
        //o que quer fazer
    });
```

$http trabalha async, o que acontece é que a variável sl só foi definida mas sem valor e a fc retorna antes da resposta do $http.

Comment: Rodolfo preciso retornar o valor data. Como faria? Se colocar return data, da o mesmo erro...

Comment: se vai usar dentro de $scope é so tratar dentro do success e atribuir ao $scope, se vai usar para outra chamada do $http coloque dentro do success, ou seja, o que tem que fazer vai fazer dentro do success

Comment: Ms como faria para retornar o data? Pois irei invoca-la dentro de outra função...